# MVC4 Linq Join Query Results And Export To .XLS

Tags: c#, linq, excel

I'm fairly new to C# and MVC and I'm stumped when trying to export data from a linq query to csv/excel.  I'm trying to keep this as simple as I can without having to use any plugins.  I've looked around and have found numerous ways of exporting queries to excel but I'm missing something somewhere.

Here's my controller

```
    public void ExportData(string searchString)
    {
        GridView grid = new GridView();

        var stuff =
           from ocs in db.OCS
           join o in db.OCSSoftwares
               on new { ocs.name, ocs.version } equals new { o.name, o.version }
           join l in db.LicModels
               on o.licModelId equals l.id
           join s in db.SoftwareTypes
               on l.softwareType equals s.type

           select new InstallvsLicense { softname = o.name, version = o.version, licmodname = l.name, vendor = l.softwareVendor, softtype = l.softwareType, pcname = ocs.pcName, facility = ocs.facility, requirespo = s.requiresPO, toberemoved = l.toBeRemoved };

            stuff = stuff.Where(s =>
            (s.facility.Contains(searchString)) &&
            ((s.requirespo.Value.Equals(true)) ||
            (s.toberemoved.Value.Equals(true)))).OrderBy(s => s.softname);

            grid.DataSource = stuff.ToList();
            grid.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + searchString.ToUpper() + " Remediation Report.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grid.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        ViewBag.searchString = searchString;
        RedirectToAction("Remediation");
    }
```

In my Index controller method, I receive the data corerctly from the same linq query but in this method I receive an "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}" erro with inner exception of null when I click the export on the following line

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + searchString.ToUpper() + " Remediation Report.xls");
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm that your `searchString` is not null.. Calling `.ToUpper()` on a null string will result in this error I believe.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the search string from the form.  I replaced searchString code and it did export a sheet but only had a couple div tages in it.

`code`
    <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "InstallvsLicense", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", searchString = ViewBag.searchString }))
        {
            <input type="submit" name="Export" id="Export" value="Export" />
        }
    </p>
 `code`

Comment: And it looks like it's not being passed to this method correctly, so it's coming in as null.

Comment: Thanks Sam and Colm Prunty, I was able to figure out the issue with passing the searchString, I used this.
`code`
        @using(Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "InstallvsLicense", new { searchString = ViewBag.searchString }))
        {
               <input type="submit" name="Export" id="Export" value="Export" />
        }
`code`